# Most efficient way to insert two rows that depend on each other

Tags: php, mysql, database-design, data-structures

I have a site that is essentially a collection of links.  A mysql database which stores users, links and votes.  My links table has two foreign keys, user_id and vote_id.  When a link is inserted into the database it will start with one vote so that means I need to insert a row into the votes table but they essentially depend on one another to exist.  I need the ID of the links for the foreign key of the votes table and vice versa.  My current "plan" is to insert a links row with a vote_id of 0, select the same row to get it's ID and then insert a votes row using the links row id as it's foreign key, select it's ID and update my original links row.  This seems really inefficient but I need to make sure users votes are recorded for time keeping and eliminating duplicate votes.  Am I going about this the wrong way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In PHP, you can use [mysql_insert_id](https://www.php.net/mysql_insert_id):

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO mytable (product) values ('kossu')");
printf("Last inserted record has id %d\n", mysql_insert_id());
```

You could use this to get the row ID of the newly inserted link.

Assuming one vote can only belong to one link, the links table should not have a vote_id column.  So you shouldn't need the identity of the newly inserted vote.

Comment: Wow, haha, you are absolutely right.  Thank you!  I have no idea what I was thinking!